# How to deal with counter cache huge mongodb data in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, phoenix-framework

the background is that I have a Ruby on Rails application that connects to a Postgresql and Mongodb database and I want to have a column in Postgres that keeps tracking the number of records in Mongodb.

I cannot use a counter cache because all of the records that persist in Mongodb come from a microservice API written in Phoenix. I separated it as a microservice to reduce the workload on the Ruby on Rails side.

So, currently, I am using a cron job executed every 10 minutes, but it takes all of the Mongodb resources and may not be the best solution in the long run.

So, if you have any suggestions, please feel free to share it with me! Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are only updating every 10 minutes the value is inherently imprecise already, so `estimatedDocumentCount` should suffice and be significantly lighter on the resources.